# VScode error - bad option: --inspect-brk=13927

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently upgraded the my VSCODE version, on Windows 7.
Since then I cannot debug running a script, here's the error:

```
bad option: --inspect-brk=13927
```

Here's my **launch.json**

```
{
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
            "runtimeArgs": ["--debug-brk"],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "name": "Launch Task",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/tasks/checkArrival.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
```

Please advise.